# Whats the 'modern' way to find common items in two Lists<T> of objects?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects, generic-list

I have two Generic Lists containing different types, for the sake of example, lets call them `Products` and `Employees`. I'm trying to find Products that are based at the same location as Employees, i.e. where `product.SiteId == emp.SiteId`

```
List<Product> lstProds;
List<Employees> lstEmps;
```

My (old skool) brain is telling me to use a `forEach` loop to find the matches but I suspect there is a ('better'/terser/faster?) way to do it using Linq. Can anyone illuminate me? All the examples I've found online deal with Lists of primitives (strings/ints) and are not especially helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would say:

```
var products = from product in lstProds
               join employee in lstEmps on product.SiteId equals employee.SiteId
               select product;
```

However, if there are *multiple* employees with the same site ID, you'll get the products multiple times. You could use `Distinct` to fix this, or build a set of site IDs:

```
var siteIds = new HashSet<int>(lstEmps.Select(emp => emp.SiteId));

var products = lstProds.Where(product => siteIds.Contains(product.SiteId));
```

That's assuming `SiteId` is an `int` - if it's an anonymous type or something similar, you may want an extra extension method:

```
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return new HashSet<T>(source);
}
```

Then:

```
var siteIds = lstEmps.Select(emp => emp.SiteId).ToHashSet();
var products = lstProds.Where(product => siteIds.Contains(product.SiteId));
```

Alternatively, if you have few employees, this will work but is relatively slow:

```
var products = lstProds.Where(p => lstEmps.Any(emp => p.SiteId == emp.SiteId));
```

Add a `ToList` call to any of these approaches to get a `List<Product>` instead of an `IEnumerable<Product>`.

Comment: I had to modify the syntax slightly to get it to work - using == to test for equality is, apparently not correct? VS tells me its 'expecting contextual keyword 'equals''.

Replacing == with equals seems to do the trick, but at this point I have no idea why? Could you elaborate please ...?

Comment: @5arx: Sorry, yes, fixed. That's just part of query expression syntax - you're not *actually* providing a single expression (`product.SiteId == employee.SiteId`) to check on every pair. Instead, you're providing two projections (`product.SiteId` and `employee.SiteId`) which are applied to each element of each side *once*, and then the keys are compared for equality.

Comment: Ok. I think I'm slowly beginning to see. Thanks much :-)