# How can I compare two lists using c#, and if I found same item in both list[No Duplication] add log

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I want to compare two lists lets say A & B.
I dont know the right way of comparing those!

I have used foreach loop[nested], which causes duplication [permutation/combination is being considered which is not required.]

eg.

```
   foreach( A a in A_list)
   {
   foreach( B b in B_list)
     {
      if(a==b)
      {
       addlog(a);
      }
     }
   }
```

Plz guide me!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827696/whats-the-modern-way-to-find-common-items-in-two-listst-of-objects

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare two lists C# linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815387/compare-two-lists-c-sharp-linq)

Comment: I'm new to c# and linq too.. any simple example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var commonElements = A.Intersect(B); 
foreach(var element in commonElements)
{
     //your processing.
}
```

You might need to implement [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) if you want to define your own equality conditions.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Intersect` or `Except` methods based on your needs. For example:

```
var commonValues = A.Intersect(B);  
var aMembersNotInB = A.Except(B); 
var bMembersNotInA = B.Except(A);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) method.

> Produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

```
var newlist = A_list.Intersect(B_list); 
foreach(var i in newlist)
{
  // do your work
}
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/9KhvRE).

Comment: if I wants to compare its attributes also then how to compare?

Comment: @Emma What do you mean compare attributes?

Comment: My list A & B has attributes, like name,id etc. So if I want to compare it with id attribute.

Comment: @Emma I don't believe there is a thing called comparing attributes. You might thinking wrong on something in my opinion..